# QThread still running after the main loop die

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I'm working on a software which has to count the emails in outlook avec update the amount every x minutes.

I created a QThread to complete this task which freezes my GUI.

Everything works fine, but, when I quit the software, the thread is still running because I used an infinity loop so that it can update the amount permanently.

I found a solution by the declaration of a global variable and a local variable with incrementation by signal.
My while loop compare them, and continue if it's ok.

As Qthread don't have the isDaemon method, I'm not sure that the thread is really dead, and not just don't do visible task anymore.

Here is an example of my code:

```
continuation=1
class App_Direction(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
        def __init__(self):
            super(App_Direction,self).__init__()
            self.setWindowTitle("test")   
            self.resize(1000,1050)
            self.move(1500,100)
            self.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt;")
            self.feed_stats_label()

        @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)    
        def feed_stats_label(self):
            self.workthread=WorkerThread()
            self.workthread.mail_sig.connect(self.modif)
            self.workthread.continuation_sig.connect(self.continuation)
            self.workthread.start()

        @QtCore.pyqtSlot(list)
        def modif (self,liste=()):
            print("Je ne recois plus le signal, car je suis mort")
        
        @QtCore.pyqtSlot(list)
        def continuation(self, arg):
            global continuation
            continuation+=1

    class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
        mail_sig = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list) 
        continuation_sig=QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super().__init__(parent)         
        def run(self):   
   
        
            self.continuation=1
            global continuation
            while self.continuation==continuation:
            print("Et ca continue encore et encore")
            self.mail_sig.emit([]) # envoi du signal de progression d'exécution
            self.continuation+=1
            self.continuation_sig.emit([self.continuation])
            time.sleep(10) 
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setStyle("Fusion")   
        app=QtWidgets.QApplication ([])
        win= App_Direction()
        win.show()      
        app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

While QThread doesn't have a Daemon flag, it does act like a Daemon. Consider your example with the continuation variable removed (and some refactoring):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import time


class AppDirection(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(AppDirection, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("test")
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt;")
        self.work_thread = None
        self.feed_stats_label()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def feed_stats_label(self):
        self.work_thread = WorkerThread()
        self.work_thread.mail_sig.connect(self.modif)
        self.work_thread.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def modif(self):
        print("I am receiving the signal")


class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    mail_sig = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("I am sending the signal.")
            self.mail_sig.emit()
            time.sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setStyle("Fusion")
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    win = AppDirection()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

When you close the Window, the thread also stops printing.